# Aiohttp session keep connections after closing

Tags: python, python-asyncio, aiohttp

I am trying to have N amount of threads repeat the same function and in each thread I am using the same proxy address that changes IP on each request. To keep same IP I use sessions. While session is opened proxy IP keeps being the same for that session.

so I am trying to do that with AIOHTTP and ASYNCIO

```py
import aiohttp
import asyncio

async def fetch_data(s):
    while True:
        async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as s:
            try:
                ###
                response = await s.get('https://example.com/',
                                            params=params, 
                                            headers=headers, timeout=5
                                            , proxy=proxys
                                            )
                result = await do_some(s)
                response = await s.get('https://example.com/',
                                            params=params, 
                                            headers=headers, timeout=5
                                            , proxy=proxys
                                            )
                pass
            except:
                ###
                pass
async def main():
    tasks = []
    for kish in range(30):
        
        tasks.append(asyncio.create_task(fetch_data()))
        
    
if __name__ == "__main__":
    asyncio.run(main())
```

and everything works fine BUT proxy panel says that connections for each session keep being alive for around 10 seconds after being closed (when I turn off the script connections are 0 immediately)

so in result with time there is increasing amount of connections to proxy which is very bad

in fetch_data() function there are several requests being sent

Comment: How long does do_some() take? The connection will be open until the function has completed. You probably also want to use `async with` on the requests as per most examples in aiohttp documentation, to ensure connections are released and reused instead of creating more connections for no reason.

Comment: @SamBull do_some takes around 10-30 seconds

Comment: also using `async with` didnt help